# Mac OS: Android Studion ADB connection error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb, emulation

I want to start my app on my device or an emulator but I cant since Adb won't start. 
Adb works just fine when called from the command line but it can't run on android studio. when I run adb start-server it runs successfully. I have changed the default android server port to 12345 since the 5037 is used.

Here are the results of adb devices and adb start-server commands:

> adb devices
>
> List of devices attached
>
> 0e6acf5f2599540e device

and

> adb start-server
>
> - daemon not running. starting it now on port 12346 *
> - daemon started successfully *

In the idea.log file I have the following error:

> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)  at
>   com.android.tools.idea.ddms.adb.AdbService$1.run(AdbService.java:232)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2016-12-27 10:44:32,484
>   [3713735]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib -
>   '/Users/nabila/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb,start-server'
>   failed -- run manually if necessary

Android Studio version: 2.2.3
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
Revision 0e9850346394-android

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to update sdk platform tools and try again

Comment: @UmarAta I already have the latest version 25.0.3

Comment: ok then are you able to use command adb devices from android studio terminal

Comment: Yes, my device is listed

Comment: so whats the problem click on play button in the center of android stuio then select your device from list and run your application

Comment: When I click on the play button I have the error: Unable to run 'adb': null '/Users/nabila/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

Comment: I have changed the default port to 12346 could this be the problem? does android studio still run adb on the 5037 port even if I have changed ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT

Comment: ok then write " adb kill-server " and then don't write any commant in terminal and click play button and if problem still persists then run command " adb devices "

Comment: Done, but their is no device shown

Comment: try my answer posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was due to running processes on the 5037 port. Even if adb has been configured to run on the 12345 port android studio still uses 5037.

Execute:

> sudo lsof -i :5037

and kill all active processes.

Answer (score 0):

try these commands

```
adb kill-server
```

to kill the existing server

then

```
adb devices
```

to start a new server

then 
go to developer options of your phone and revoke all usb authorization then reconnect your device with useb and it will ask to accept the RSA fingerprint and you done.

you may also use `adb -P 1234 start-server`
to start the adb server to 1234 port

Comment: No I still have the same problem

Comment: is your device visible in Android Studio

Comment: No, I still have the same error  Unable to run 'adb': null '/Users/nabila/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb,start-‌​server' failed -- run manually if necessary

Comment: Ok now i have another solution, click on build menu then click build apk then click on show in explorer then copy that apk to your mobile either by using usb as usb storage or copy it to the sdcard by plugging it with sd card reader then install in phone

Comment: Thanks @UmarAta I have already done that by using the command gradlew installDebug. What I want is to debug the app via android studion

Comment: According to you . I run this command adb -P 1234 start-server then I opened Android Studio and I found my device listed there and when I click on run button it got run in my device

Comment: Thanks @UmarAta for your time. I have solved my problem, apparently even if I have change the adb port to 12345 android studio still uses 5037. I didn't see that the port was used by java (I should have used sudo lsof -i :5037 instead of lsof -i :5037) I have killed all java processes and now it works just fine. Thanks again.